# How to change select box selected option depending on Ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form that contains textboxes and a selectbox. I am sending and Ajax request to a PHP page and i'am filling this form automatically depending on that request. There is no problem about filling textboxes but how can determine the selected select box option ? Any help would be appriciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#companyFillSelectBox").change(function(){
        var value = $("select#companyFillSelectBox option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'companyFill.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data:{companyID:value},
            success:function(answer){
                $('#companyNameText').val(answer[0].companyName);
                $('#companyAddressTextArea').val(answer[0].companyAddress);
                $('#companyNetAdressText').val(answer[0].companyWebAddress);
                $('#companyPhoneText').val(answer[0].companyPhone);
                $('#companyFaxText').val(answer[0].companyFax);
                $('#companyCeoText').val(answer[0].companyCeo);
                $('#companyHRText').val(answer[0].hrDirector);
                $('#numOfIengText').val(answer[0].numOfIENG);
                $('#numOfEngText').val(answer[0].numOfENG);
                $('#numOfWhiteCollarsText').val(answer[0].numOfIENG);
                $('#totalEmpText').val(answer[0].numOfEmployees);
                $('#establishmentYearText').val(answer[0].yearOfEstablishment);
                $("#fieldOfBusinessSelectBox option[value=answer[0].yearOfEstablishment]").attr('selected', 'selected');
            },
            error:function(){
                alert("An error has occured !");
            }         
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it the way you attempted would have just taken a syntax fix:

```
$("#fieldOfBusinessSelectBox option[value=" + answer[0].yearOfEstablishment +"]").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

However, you can do it the same way you did all the others:

```
$("#fieldOfBusinessSelectBox").val(answer[0].yearOfEstablishment);
```

Comment: In the first solution, 'attr()' won't work. Use 'prop()' instead. I'd also like to add that in case of multiple options with same value, the first solution (with prop) will select the last appearing option while the second (with val) will select the first appearing option.

Comment: `attr` does work - 'prop' is not a requirement, despite it being common on here to see people insist you **must** use `prop`.  What version of jQuery is he running?  We don't know.  And since the question doesn't even begin to mention duplicate values it's not relevant to bring that up.  They could be disabled, or not visible.  They could be added dynamically after this code has run.  There are no end of "what ifs", so I just stick to the question ;)

Comment: I stick with the importance of my comment. 'attr' doesn't trigger selection in FireFox. There is a reason people here insist on that. Besides, using 'selected' attribute is a messy way of setting value. The only scene where it is preferable is in case of duplicate value options (i.e. default 0 with a blank option on top).